# How to keep a vertical row of multiple soap bars vertically instead of typical horizontal one-soap dish?

Tags: personal-care, efficiency, bathroom, organization

So for illustration i have organic type of soap bars that I use now thanks to the TSA liquid drama.

[image: vertical stack of herbal organic soap bars]

The slimmer ones in the pic are 3 cm exact and I go through varieties that are thicker as well as but thinner.

I hate soap bar dishes as they are usually horizontal & increase the contact surface area;

- more sticky goo/ soap residue ,
- harder soap release for use,
- more loss of soap &
- less efficient use of shelf space

Note: (Currently a corner shelf raised above / around shoulder; Removed the one near elbow height as due to compact bathroom i tended to hit my elbows on it, ouch!).

I was originally thinking of something like a letter holder / envelope holder types of stuff that's typical on a desk, but not sure if thickness would work and material would survive water & soap in the bathroom. 
I'm guessing some steel/ chrome stuff might survive.

I was thinking on the lines of books & other stuff that are kept vertically (they don't stick to each other so separators may be more essential for soaps)

Open to other ideas.

Comment: Are you looking to keep just one at a time for use or the six as displayed in the picture to choose from?

Comment: Preferably more than one. Not necessarily all 6, but it'd nice to be able to keep a few

Comment: Wow! Has the TSA invaded your home, too? All you might need is a travel-size bar for the road/sky. Go back to using whatever liquid soap makes you happy in your own space. I heard that tiny bars of soap are also available in some hotel rooms and public rest rooms to relieve you of the burden (responsibility) of carrying your own supply.

Comment: TIP: I see that you have your soap neatly wrapped. Your soap bars will last longer if you unwrap the bars and let the moisture evaporate. Soft soap bars allow water to mix and dissolve them. Let them harden while you store them unused.

Answer (score 4):

You could try pressing a round, flat, strong rare-earth magnet into the side or end of each of as many different soap bars you wish.

The soft soaps in your photo will easily hold one securely.

Suspend/hang the bars from something magnetic such as the shower curtain rod or the side of any porcelain bathtub to allow you to see, and freely choose from among them independently. This also allows the soap bars to hang free to dry without a tray of goo [sic] at all.

Comment: How does that help me keep a vertical stack of several soaps - I like the Magnetic idea, but these soaps may not hold well to the magnet, and I do not have or can have a suitable Big rod to attach magnets too.

But if I could find a Steel letter/ paper holder this might be a way to "hold" the soaps on the walls

Comment: @AlexS I was unaware of the necessity of having a stack of them. You showed a row of them. Could you edit your photo to show exactly what the stack should look like? I'm sure we can solve this. By the way, how does the net allow a stack of your TSA-approved format soaps?

Comment: sorry I meant a vertical standing row of them

Answer (score 3):

I use a small shallow "tray" with a Chinese plastic chop-stick (cut in half) lying on the bottom to support the bar(s) of soap. The air circulation is improved.

[image: DIY chop-stick soap tray]

Soap residue that does collect can be wiped-up and used with a washcloth.

Comment: Could you include an image? I can't picture what "a couple of plastic sticks" looks like.

Comment: A picture would really help

Comment: Is that leaning oval a half chopstick? You said you use it. Lovely diagram. I'm still wondering what/ how a chopstick is attached to soap to hold it up?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming here that space is the primary concern. So instead of stacking soap bars vertically you could stick each bar into a mesh bag. The mesh should be wide enough to allow use of the soap bar without actually removing the soap from the bag. I am thinking of some material like nylon hair nets ...

[image: A hair net for kitchen staff, also called a snood]

... or the stuff these so called 'puff sponge mesh net balls' are made from (*honi soit qui mal y pense*).

[image: puff sponge]

Then you could install some of these cup holder hooks, that are commonly used for hanging cups or mugs on their handles. Screw them in, so you can hang the soap bars in their mesh bags on them. Place a nice plate below to catch any drippings.

This way the soap bars can dry out completely after each use. All contact areas to trap water and the annoying goo question will be eliminated. If you want, you can always take the soap bars out of the mesh bags for use. In that case you might be better off making open bags for them out of your hair net.

You could tie a hair net with string to shut it and effectively create your bag this way. Then you could leave the strings at different lengths to hang the soap bars at various hights. This should make the whole thing more space efficient still.

Or if you prefer you could tie the string just at the side of the hair net so you could use the already existing opening to have an option to remove the soap from the net if you prefer this.

This is just a general idea. There should be a lot of room to adapt this system to your personal preferences.

Comment: I like the net direction, just not keen on how abrasive it will be on the skin. Is it possible to get nets that are more softer like natural fibres? How could I do an open easy access net? (Any diagrams: pics would be great help to visualise what you've written)

Comment: Alex, I have edited the answer a bit and added pictures I found on the web. Especially the picture of the hair net should make things more clear as it is basically already what you were looking for, except for the string to hang it. Keep in mind you could attach it as it is without the string to a hook, however I think the string would make it more elegant.

Comment: Regarding having softer nets: I don't know of any nets like this from natural fibres. I don't think any natural fibres would be any softer than nylon, with the possible exception of silk maybe. Natural fibres also tend to absorb more moisture and introduce the gooeyness problem again. If this isn't an issue for you, why not stick the soap into a cotton sock?

Comment: A hair net is the softest net I've found. Much softer than the monofilament weaves for veggies packaging.

Comment: @Flint thanks for the Netted suggestion I found some net pouches and apparently some with natural fibres also. I think I might try to leverage yours as well stans answers

Answer (score 1):

I would use a paper spike like this: 
[image: paper spike] 
Install soaps in reverse use order using sharpened spindle, at center of cake, to bore through gently, each soap. To use soaps, remove all soaps, place on dry section of corner shelf. Use soaps in order, one at a time, placing each "used" cake onto spindle after use. Each cake will be minimally wet because you've used it directly after picking it up without setting it anywhere it could take on water. Continue until all soaps are applied and back on spindle. The time between individual soap use should allow each soap on spindle to dry adequately enough to avoid sticking or mushiness. Affix spindle to  a dry area of shower with clear, silicone caulking or another method, depending on surrounds.